# Error (RequestDisallowedByPolicy): Resource XXX was disallowed by policy(...Require a tag on resources...)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am proceeding with the publication of a function in azure. When creating the "Function App" from the wizard I have the following error: "*... Require a tag on resources ...*"

**Error:**
[image: View error]

I am suspecting that most likely I should add some "tags" that are required for the creation of the "Function App". If I'm correct, how could I configure that from my c # code?

Here I attach the code of my function. How could I assign the values ​​of the tags that the assigned policies request me from my code in c #?

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is from your work group's policy.

Search **Policy** on portal, navigate to **Definition** to check if your subscription set this policy: [Require a tag on resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies), which Enforces existence of a tag. Find out what the tag name is needed, such as '`Region`'.
[image]

## The solution:

Add the tag when you create your Function app. Such as:  `"Region":"centralus"`
[image]

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. But how could I send those tags from the definition of my function from my code in c #?

Comment: It is not recommended that adding tag from Function code. @Arinka If you want add tag automatically, the best choice is using policy, too.

Comment: My problem was when publishing my "function". In this process, the "Function App" had to be created and there it was giving me the error because there were policies that required that I enter some tags. I solved it by creating the "Function App" from the azure portal because there was a tab to enter the tags. However, I am interested in knowing if those same tags can be assigned as an attribute in the function or somewhere to make the publication from the Visual Studio wizard without having to switch to the "azure portal". Thank you very much Doris, your answer clarifies the picture more.

Comment: @Arinka I think there is no way to do this.